# React + react-bootstrap- How to set default activeKey selection in Nav

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to have my "Home" Nav.Link marked as active so that it appears white in the header when the site initially loads with no /route (localhost:3000).

I have found that you aren't meant to use defaultActiveKey when using controlled tabs, which if I understand correctly is what I am doing in my Nav header. Is there another way to accomplish this using activeKey, or automatically routing to /home?

[This is what the page currently looks like when the site is first loaded with no /route specified](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97poN.png)

[This is what I would like it to look like, so that it is clear from the header that you are on the home page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwfhh.png)

```
import React from 'react';
import { Navbar, Nav } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { LinkContainer } from 'react-router-bootstrap';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { faHome, faBoxOpen } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';

const Header = (props) => {
    const { location } = props;
    return (
        <Navbar bg="primary" variant="dark" expand="md" > 
            <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" /> 
            <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
                <Nav defaultActiveKey="/home" activeKey={location.pathname} className="mr-auto">
                    <LinkContainer to="/home">
                        <Nav.Link><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faHome} />&nbsp;Home</Nav.Link>
                    </LinkContainer>
                    <LinkContainer to="/products">
                        <Nav.Link><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faBoxOpen} />&nbsp;Products</Nav.Link>
                    </LinkContainer>
                </Nav>
            </Navbar.Collapse>
        </Navbar>
    );
};

export default withRouter(Header);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can Just use the **active** in your class name;
Like

```
"nav active"
```

Comment: That does make it white on load, but then the active class stays applied after I click my Product Nav.Link

Answer (score 0):

```
function App() {
  const [activeNavbar, setActiveNavbar] = React.useState(0);

  const NavbarActivehandleOnClick = navbar=> {
    setActiveNavbar(navbar);
  };

  const numberOfNav = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
  const nav= numberOfNav.map((el, navbar) => {
    return (
      <button
        key={navbar}
        onClick={() => handleOnClick(index)} 
        className={activeNavbar === navbar ? "active" : "unactive"}
      >
        {el}
      </button>
    );
  });
  return <div className="App">{nav}</div>;
}

ReactDOM.render( <App /> , document.getElementById('root'))
```

Sorry for the late response please try this one.

```
.active {
  background-color: green
}
```

and add these links in the public/index.html

```
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```